# jquery fade to after scrolling certain distance

Tags: jquery, fadeto

I have a personal website, [www.derekgoss.com](http://www.derekgoss.com), that I'm working on (note that it is far from finished - still need content, responsiveness, etc.). 
When I scroll down and reach the first content box, I would like the navigation bar at the top to **fadeTo(1000, .35)**, not fadeIn/Out. Likewise, once i scroll back up past the content box I would like the bar to fade back to its original opacity. Additionally, if the bar is faded out, I would like it to fade back to its original opacity when the user hovers their mouse over it, and go back once the mouse leaves. 
Something similar to this worked with the fadeOut/In methods, however once I tried to use the fadeTo methods it stopped working.
I already set the opacity of the navigation bar to 1.
Here is my best shot, but it isn't working:

```
  $(function(){
   var headertop = $("#aboutheader").offset().top;

   $(window).scroll(function(){
           if( $(window).scrollTop() > headertop ) {
                   $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(1000,.35);

                   $("#navigationbar").hover(
                   function() {
                   $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(500,1);
                   }, function() {
                   $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(1000,.35);
                   }
                   );
           } else {
                   $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(1000, 1);
           }
   }); 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I made a jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/smC3f/ It really seems to be the fadeTo method, because changing it to raw css manipulation it workx fine.

Comment: Ah wait a minute, i think i got it! It is because while scrolling you initiate the fadeTo over and overagain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y2gY8/

The problem with your code was, that it triggers the fades over and over again while scrolling and so they stack and fire one by one. My version works but could be a little bit optimized I guess.

```
$(function () {
    var headertop = $("#aboutheader").offset().top;
    var hoveractive = false;
    var fadeout = true;
    var fadein = true;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > headertop && fadeout) {
            hoveractive = true;
            fadeout = false;
            fadein = true;
            $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(1000, .35);
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= headertop && fadein) {
            hoveractive = false;
            fadein = false;
            fadeout = true;
            $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(1000, 1);
        }
    });

    $("#navigationbar").hover(function () {
        if (hoveractive) {
            $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    }, function () {
        if (hoveractive) {
            $("#navigationbar").fadeTo(500, .35);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks, especially for the super quick response and the wonderful fiddle. The true/false bit is brilliant. I will be sure to give you special thanks in the final file. I had to think about the logic for a few minutes, but it seems pretty optimized to me! (I would upvote if I had enough reputation haha my apologies - best answer is all I can do)